# Is policy applicable to only full set or also subsets of attributes

Tags: xacml, xacml3

I am looking at the [XACMLv3 specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html) and have a question about the applicability of policies and policy sets in case one of the combining algorithms allows for the situation that underlying rules or policies act on different sets of attributes from the request, returning a valid response.
For example, a policy would define two rules with the first rule acting upon the attributes [A, B, C], the second rule would act upon attributes [A, B, D] and the rule combining algorithm is [First-applicable](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959679). My question is what set of attributes the policy is applicable to: is it only applicable to the full set of attributes [A, B, C, D] or also to the subsets [A, B, C] and [A, B, D]: i.e. is this policy selected for evaluation in case the set of attributes is the full set or is it also evaluated for the subsets? Sections [2.2](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959479) and [2.3](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/errata01/os/xacml-3.0-core-spec-errata01-os-complete.html#_Toc489959480) mention nothing about this.

Answer (score 1):

The PDP will attempt to match the incoming request against `rule 1`; if there is a match, the PDP will reply with `Permit` or `Deny`and the evaluation stops. If `rule 1` does not match, the PDP attempts to match with `rule 2`. If there is a match, the PDP replies with `Permit` or `Deny`. If neither `rule 1` or `rule 2` match, the PDP returns `NotApplicable`.

Comment: So, policies and policy sets are selected based on the combination of attribute subsets used within the rules: i.e. this policy is evaluated because it uses subsets [A,B, C] and [A,B,D]? Selecting which policies are to be evaluated seems very complex to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check section C.8 for complete pseudocode

```
Decision firstApplicableEffectRuleCombiningAlgorithm(Rule[] rules)
{
  for( i = 0 ; i < lengthOf(rules) ; i++ )
  {
          Decision decision = evaluate(rules[i]);
          if (decision == Deny)
          {
                return Deny;
          }
          if (decision == Permit)
          {
                return Permit;
          }
          if (decision == NotApplicable)
          {
                continue;
          }
          if (decision == Indeterminate)
          {
               return Indeterminate;
          }
   }
   return NotApplicable;
}
```

That means in your case the first rule is evaluated(which means the attributes[A,B,C] will be applicable)

--if have "Permit" or "deny" then it won't go further to evaluate the second rule(Which means the attributes[A,B,D] won't be evaluated).

--if have "NotApplicable" then it would go further to evaluate second rule(which means the attributes[A,B,D] will be applicable)

I actually use this free [Xacml Editor](https://youtu.be/3_S04qrmBSg) myself. It’s a great, easy to use gui based and syntax guided editor to create XACML documents very conveniently. All you need to do is create an account on their website and then you can download it.

P.S. I work for the company that provides this XACML Editor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice: how the combining algorithms work are not my problem but it is more that it is not clear to me how policies and policy sets are selected for evaluation. It seems so complex to me and expensive for that reason, that selecting policies in a large / heavy loaded system may become a serious bottleneck. Any experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

A Policy(Set) is selected for evaluation if and only if its `<Target>` matches the request, regardless of any child Rule, Policy, etc. inside.

In your case, if the request attributes are:

- subject-organization = 'Acme'
- subject-role = 'role1'
- subject-auth-method = 'basic'
- resource-id = 'res1'
- action-id = 'read'

... but the policy's Target is: `subject-organization = 'Wayne'` and `subject-role = 'role2'` (using a XACML AllOf for the AND), then the policy will not be selected for evaluation, even if the policy has a rule `rule1` with Target matching all the last 3 attributes of the request:

`subject-auth-method = 'basic'` and `resource-id = 'res1'` and `action-id = 'read'`
No rule in the policy will be evaluated.

Comment: The situation you describe for a request matching [A, B, C] but the policy's Target only matching attributes [E, F], to me looks like a real error. This is like writing unreachable code and probably indicates a mistake by the policy author. For policy sets detecting such ambiguity seems a hard to detect issue.

Comment: In the specs (see 3.3.2.1), two methods are suggested for calculating the policy’s and policy sets target: “In one method, the <Target> element of the outer <PolicySet> or <Policy> (the "outer component") is calculated as the union of all the <Target> elements of the referenced <PolicySet>, <Policy> or <Rule> elements (the "inner components").  In another method, the <Target> element of the outer component is calculated as the intersection of all the <Target> elements of the inner components.”

Comment: The problem I have with these two methods is that, as far as I can tell now, this would make a policy act differently  depending on how the target is calculated

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding. I rephrased my second paragraph with more explicit syntax and more concrete example.

Comment: Regarding the §3.3.2.1 you mention, I was assuming that the first way is used in my previous example indeed, i.e. we assume the Policy(Set)'s Target is declared by the Policy(Set) writer explicity. I don't recommend the other way (with two possible Target computation methods) because I have the same problem you have, and the spec (3.3.2.1, 2nd paragraph) confirms it (quote): *The results of evaluation in each case will be very different*. Therefore, I consider it error-prone and confusing for policy writers.